# Types of Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a simple function as seen below:

```
function createData(name, email,role,date_joined) 
{
    return { name, email,role,date_joined };
}
```

Is the returned value a simple javascript object and if not what is the type?

Comment: Yes. It's an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say yes. If you test the function using the [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator, it will return an object. While typeof reports an object even for an array (as mentioned in the comments) you could also check with the `[isArray][2]`.

```js
function createData(name, email,role,date_joined) 
{
    return { name, email,role,date_joined };
}

let typeOfFunction = createData("Yagi", "goat@goat.com", "Billy", "16-May-21");

console.log(typeOfFunction)
console.log(typeof typeOfFunction) // object
console.log(Array.isArray(typeOfFunction)) //false
```

The function is generating a new object from the data that it returns.

Apologies if I have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

The type is of object. In JavaScript, you can actually check the types of things in code using the `typeof` operator. See the example below.

```js
function createData(name, email,role,date_joined) 
{
    return { name, email,role,date_joined };
}

console.log(typeof createData(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

As has been pointed out, many things like arrays, Dates, null are all classed as object by `typeof`. However, this is actually correct since an array is an object with integer keys, a Date is an instantiation of the Date class, and `null` is just an object variable that doesn't currently point to an object.

The thing to remember is that anything in JavaScript that can have an attribute assigned to it is in fact an object (except for functions that are a little different). You can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) for the definitions of what the different types are. A brief summary would be. These are the primitives:

```
undefined : typeof instance === "undefined"
Boolean : typeof instance === "boolean"
Number : typeof instance === "number"
String : typeof instance === "string"
BigInt : typeof instance === "bigint"
Symbol : typeof instance === "symbol"
```

These are the objects and functions:

```
Function: typeof instance === "function"
Object: typeof instance === "object"
```

Comment: Be careful with this because `typeof []` also results in "object".

Comment: As well as `Date`, `null`, `Error`, `RegExp`... etc.

Comment: That's because they are all objects in JavaScript. An array is an object with integer keys, a Date is an instantiation of the Date class. Null is just an object variable that doesn't currently point to an object

Comment: Precisely, so your answer is naive at best

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect these facts

Comment: There was a proposal to change the type of `null` to be actually `"null"`, but it would have resulted into many problems, in many libraries. But `null` should be considered as a primitive and not as an object.